# SQL query plan and minimum row size exceeds the maximum allowable of 8060 bytes

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting the following error when running a query against my local database :

> The query processor could not produce a query plan because a worktable is required, and its minimum row size exceeds the maximum allowable of 8060 bytes. A typical reason why a worktable is required is a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause in the query. If the query has a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause, consider reducing the number and/or size of the fields in the clause. Consider using prefix (LEFT()) or hash (CHECKSUM()) of fields for grouping or prefix for ordering. Note however that this will change the behavior of the query.

This occurs when running a query that looks similar to this (apolgies for the lack of detail) :

```
SELECT <about 183 columns>
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tvf1(<params>) tvf1
  ON tvf1.id = tableA.X1
INNER JOIN tvf2(<params>) tvf2
  ON tvf2.id = tableA.X2
INNER JOIN tvf3(<params>) tvf3
  ON tvf3.id = tableA.X3
INNER JOIN tvf4(<params>) tvf4
  ON tvf4.id = tableA.X4
INNER JOIN tvf5(<params>) tvf5
  ON tvf5.id = tableA.X5
```

The table-valued-functions above all use a combination of `GROUP BY`, `ROW_NUMBER()` and other aggregation functions.
While binary debugging, commenting out any 2 of the above joins results in the error not occurring, doesnt matter which though.

My database is running on `Compatibility Level 2019`.
If i try setting `Legacy Cardinality Estimation` to `On` then the error no longer happens but I dont understand what this setting does.

edit :
If the database compatibility level is `2016` then everything works as expected as well

A concern i have is that the production database might be upgraded in future and this error could occur.

Edit :
I've managed to get the column count down to a handful now however my results are inconsistent.

```
SELECT 
         
        Other =  TvfGroupData.Other             
        ,GroupA = TvfGroupData.GroupA
        ,GroupB = TvfGroupData.GroupB
        ,GroupC = TvfGroupData.GroupC

        
    , [Max Created Date] = 
        (SELECT MAX(Value)
            FROM (VALUES 
                (Tvf1.CreatedDate)
                ,(Tvf2.CreatedDate)
                ,(Tvf3.CreatedDate)
                --,(TvfGroupData.CreatedDate)
                ,(Tvf3.CreatedDate)
                ,(Tvf4.CreatedDate)
            ) AS AllValues(Value)
        )

        
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN Tvf1() ...
LEFT JOIN Tvf2() ...
LEFT JOIN TvfGroupData() ...
LEFT JOIN Tvf3() ...
LEFT JOIN Tvf4() ...
```

In the above query the following scenarios work :

1. excluding only GroupA column.
2. excluding only GroupB, GroupC column

Other combinations all fail with the error :

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

Comment: What are you doing with all those columns?

Comment: This is for an end-user report. Lots of statistical data etc

Comment: I've never needed anywhere near 180+ columns in a single query in 20 years of using databases. Are you using a lot of (n)varchar columns that are lazily sized?

Comment: there are the datatypes in the table with the number of columns that they have :
bigint(5)
date(2)
datetime2(4)
decimal(73)
int(41)
nvarchar(57)
varchar(1)

Comment: I would suggest that is it unlikely you need 183 columns in your result set; especially as the data engine is effectively telling you that the rows are too "wide". I also hope that your TVFs are inline functions, and not multi-line ones,

Comment: I edited my post to include that everything runs as expected when the compatibility level is 2016 as well

Comment: There is a query hint you can apply for "robust plans" that will probably fix this without compat level sledgehammer but it is likely you should rethink the need for this anyway

Comment: I think your first port of call is to do some detective work and start building your query from the minimum working state until you encounter the join / tvf that's causing the problem - can you select data from each tvf in isolation? Is it including one specific tvf that produces the error? are your varchar columns sized to be large enough for the data required but no larger? hopefully not 57 varchar(max) columns!

Comment: Are you table-valued-functions inline ones? If yes and you change them to multi-statement form, does something change?

Comment: One more idea - can you play with query hints? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/craigfr/maximum-row-size-and-query-hints

Comment: THe use of UDFs here probably part of the problem.

Comment: Edited with updates

Comment: I suspect it may be *scalar* UDFs, which in 2019 are inlined. You may find that downcasting the columns to a smaller size may help

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality estimator is how SQL Server generates the execution plan, meaning how the engine will execute and assemble the disparate sets of data.

The recent changes in the engine usually (but not always) result in better execution plans, leading to faster queries response while consuming less resources.

If you look into how SQL Server processes a query statement, the full data set is gathered before the unwanted columns are excluded.  When multiple data sets are combined, the engine may exclude columns before joining to another set, or it may join the sets before excluding columns.  It is based on what the engine "sees" in your data patterns (statistics).

UDFs are a frequent stumbling block for the query plan optimizer as a poorly formed function masks the data statistics and prevents the engine from efficiently piecing the data together.

All that to say, the updated engine is looking at your data and determining it is more efficient to combine multiple sets before eliminating unwanted columns.

I believe you may be able to fix this by subselecting the columns you need from your functions before joining to the outer set.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select SpecificColumns from tableA) as tableA
INNER JOIN (select SpecificColumns from tvf1(<params>)) as tvf1
  ON tvf1.id = tableA.X1
INNER JOIN (select SpecificColumns from tvf2(<params>)) as tvf2
  ON tvf2.id = tableA.X2
```

Alternatively, you may want to reconsider the Do-Everything query approach to reporting.
At ~8kb per row, you're likely passing a tremendous amount of data to your reporting system.

You may also give Cross Apply a try.

```
SELECT <about 183 columns>
FROM tableA
CROSS APPLY tvf1(<params>) tvf1
CROSS APPLY tvf2(<params>) tvf2
WHERE tvf1.id = tableA.X1
  AND tvf2.id = tableA.X2
```

CROSS APPLY can instruct the optimizer to process sets in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

Ive stil been unable to track down the exact problem.

My workaround for now has been to evaluate the table-valued-functions into table variables/temp tables and then join onto them instead

So it has been changed to something like this

```
DECLARE @tvf1 AS TABLE ....
INSERT INTO @tvf1 SELECT * FROM tvf1()...
DECLARE @tvf2 AS TABLE ....
INSERT INTO @tvf2 SELECT * FROM tvf2()...
DECLARE @tvf3 AS TABLE ....
INSERT INTO @tvf3 SELECT * FROM tvf3()...


SELECT <about 183 columns>
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN @tvf1 tvf1
  ON tvf1.id = tableA.X1
INNER JOIN @tvf2 tvf2
  ON tvf2.id = tableA.X2
INNER JOIN @tvf3 tvf3
  ON tvf3.id = tableA.X3
```